# Crear imagen con lo que esta en un tabcontrol c#

Tags: c#, .net

Hola queria saber como podria crear una imagen con todo lo que este dentro de una pestaña de un tabcontrol, dentro de esta tengo varios picturebox y la idea seria crear una imagen que muestre todos esos picturebox no se si me hice entender

Comment: Hola Crisheld, Te sugiero que mires [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funciona StackOverflow Español y obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: gracias, lo tendré en cuenta para la próxima.

Answer (score 1):

```
        Size s = actual.Size;
        Bitmap memoryImage;
        using (Graphics myGraphics = CreateGraphics())
        {
            memoryImage = new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        }
        using (Graphics memoryGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(memoryImage))
        {
            Point screenPoint = PointToScreen(actual.Location);
            memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(screenPoint.X, screenPoint.Y + 10, 0, 0, s);
        }

        memoryImage.Save("imagen.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

No se si esto le sirva a alguien en el futuro, pero creo una haciendo una captura de pantalla en las coordenadas donde este mi tabControl que en ese caso se llama actual.
este codigo lo encontre aca
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/cd8061aa-964d-4de9-9e24-930d5eca21a9/guardar-contenido-de-un-panel-como-imagen?forum=vcses

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que la pestaña de la que quieres crear es tabPage1 el codigo sería así:

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(tabPage1.Width, tabPage1.Height))
{
   tabPage1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));
   bmp.Save(@"C:\hola\ejemplo.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png); 
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias pero estaba usando algo parecido y me creaba una imagen en blanco, ya di con la solución y es hacer una captura de pantalla